# How to plot different CSV file data into a single graph, day as reference at x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I have written a code to plot several CSV file into single graph, using day as reference @ x-axis.

```
    CSV 1:
                         Value
    time                                                                       
    2012-02-10 11:03:45  520429.598
    2012-07-17 09:12:07  522155.535
    ...                  ...
    2014-07-19 12:57:36  626192.186
    2014-07-19 12:59:52  705789.899
```

3-years of data

```
    CSV 2:
                         Value
    time                                                                       
    2014-02-10 11:03:45  520429.598
    2014-02-17 12:12:07  522155.535
    ...                  ...
    2014-07-19 12:57:36  626192.186
    2014-07-19 12:59:52  705789.899
```

6-months of data

```
    CSV 3:
                         Value
    time                                                                       
    2013-02-10 11:03:45  520429.598
    2013-02-17 12:12:07  522155.535
    ...                  ...
    2014-07-19 12:57:36  626192.186
    2014-07-19 12:59:52  705789.899
```

18-months of data

...

```
    CSV n:
                         Value
    time                                                                       
    2011-11-10 11:03:45  520429.598
    2011-11-11 09:12:07  522155.535
    ...                  ...
    2011-12-18 12:57:36  626192.186
    2011-12-19 12:59:52  705789.899
```

2-months of data

I am finding difficulty to plot all in one graph from (0,0) reason every csv file starts with different dates, so I was trying to convert timestamp into no. of days, so that I can plot all in one go with starting from day 1, but couldn't get it right, any suggestions please!

for example:- csv 2 (6-months) should fall short as compared to csv 1 (3-years). How to proceed, any hint, help highly appreciated....

```
    data1 = pd.read_csv(path1,names=['time','Value'],sep=',', index_col=0, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=False)
    data2 = pd.read_csv(path2,names=['time','Value'],
                                sep=',', index_col=0, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=False)
    ...

    datan = pd.read_csv(pathn,names=['time','Value'],
                                sep=',', index_col=0, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=False)

    ax1 = pd.rolling_mean(data1['Value'],100).plot()
    ax2 = pd.rolling_mean(data2['Value'],100).plot()
    ...
    axn = pd.rolling_mean(datan['Value'],100).plot()

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi. Could you please show a complete example? What libraries are you importing? What is `pd`?

Comment: Thanks @Schorsch, 1. The complete example, you want me to show the plot (image)? have shown you only 8 plot "http://i.imgur.com/CrQTt0D.png" 2. 'Pandas', 'matplotlib' libraries are included 3. ->import pandas as pd<-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try letting matplotlib handle turning the dates into your x-axis coordinates. I had a similar problem a little while ago and was able to plot multiple time series with different date ranges.

**Edit:** I think this should do what you want. It plots Value based on the time difference in days between each row and the time in the first row of the file.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

csv1 = io.StringIO(u"""time,Value\n2012-02-10 11:03:45,520429.598\n2013-07-19 12:57:36,626192.186\n2014-07-19 12:59:52,705789.899""")
csv2 = io.StringIO(u"""time,Value\n2013-02-11 11:03:45,420429.598\n2013-05-17 12:12:07,522155.535\n2014-07-19 12:57:36,626192.186\n2014-07-19 12:59:52,705789.899""")
dat1 = pd.read_csv(csv1, parse_dates=['time'])
dat2 = pd.read_csv(csv2, parse_dates=['time'])

dat1['timeDiff'] = (dat1['time'] - dat1['time'][0]).astype('timedelta64[D]')
dat2['timeDiff'] = (dat2['time'] - dat2['time'][0]).astype('timedelta64[D]')

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(dat1['timeDiff'],dat1['Value'])
ax.plot(dat2['timeDiff'],dat2['Value'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks @jdaly, as you have mentioned I would like to hand it over to matplotlib but how since every date is different from one and another, need to convert date&time format into days then I guess would easier, how could I achieve that, any suggestions please would be highly appreciable. Thanks for your time...

Comment: Hello @jdaly again,  have copied the plot link [link] (http://i.imgur.com/1ca63HI.png), all the graphs doesn't start from the origin(0,0), coz date&time influencing and even few graphs are hidding on left hand side, how could I fix this any suggestions please

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, even though each of these data sets start at different dates, you want to plot them as though they were starting from the same date?

So if data1 began on Feb 2, 2012 and data2 began on Feb 2, 2014, they should each begin on the same x coordinate in your graph?

Comment: Exactly mate!!! I want to plot all the graphs begin on the same x-coordinate, thanks

Comment: Ok, see my edits above and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks @jdaly, thanks for code, I have small problem now, two months of cvs1 has 50,000 data Value and two months of csv2 has 4,000 data Value and so on, it's really hard to fit all the graph for two months at same size, [link](http://i.imgur.com/A1eB4rY.png) from the graph, only two months of data is shown but all the signals doesn't fit. Python is plotting based on the data points but I want to plot based on days (for ex: 2 months/60 days). Is there any logic to apply, or methods, any suggestions are highly appreciable, since I am in this for long time. Thank you very much.

Comment: The code I posted should have the same range of x for data of the same length of time but different numbers of points (e.g. 2 months with 20 data points should have the same range on the graph as 2 months with 200 points). You might make sure your date parser is actually converting your dates into datetime objects. Try `dat1.dtypes` to verify that.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably the easiest to put all you're data in a single `Dataframe`, then you would only have to execute commands like the `rolling_mean` once. Since your example is not easy to replicate it might depend on how your data is actually structured. But you could loop over the `csv's` and collect all individual Dataframes in a list or something, perhaps store some `id` as well, and then use `pd.concat` to merge all Dataframes into a single one. The rolling_mean and any other command including the plotting is very straightforward from then on.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io

csv1 = io.StringIO("""date time    Value
    2012-02-10 11:03:45  520429.598
    2012-07-17 09:12:07  522155.535
    2014-07-19 12:57:36  626192.186
    2014-07-19 12:59:52  705789.899""")

csv2 = io.StringIO("""date time    Value                                                                     
    2014-02-10 11:03:45  520429.598
    2014-02-17 12:12:07  522155.535
    2014-07-19 12:57:36  626192.186
    2014-07-19 12:59:52  705789.899""")

csv3 = io.StringIO("""date time    Value                                                                  
    2013-02-10 11:03:45  520429.598
    2013-02-17 12:12:07  522155.535
    2014-07-19 12:57:36  626192.186
    2014-07-19 12:59:52  705789.899""")

csv4 = io.StringIO("""date time    Value                                                                      
    2011-11-10 11:03:45  520429.598
    2011-11-11 09:12:07  522155.535
    2011-12-18 12:57:36  626192.186
    2011-12-19 12:59:52  705789.899""")

csvs = []
for csv in [csv1, csv2, csv3, csv4]:

    df = pd.read_csv(csv, delim_whitespace=True, skipinitialspace=True,
                     index_col='datetime', 
                     parse_dates={'datetime': ['date', 'time']}, 
                     dayfirst=False)

    csvs.append(df)

dfall = pd.concat(csvs, keys=['csv1', 'csv2', 'csv3', 'csv4'], axis=1)
ax = pd.rolling_mean(dfall, 100, min_periods=1).plot()
```

Comment: Thanks @Rutger Kassies, I was doing rolling_mean separately coz every data set needs different window size, How do I collect all individual Dataframes in a list? every CSV has got different date and time with 16 columns and I am using only date time column and column 5 to plot the graph. what about the x-axis? Thank you so much for your time...

Comment: Hello @Rutger Kassies again,  have copied the plot link [link] (http://i.imgur.com/1ca63HI.png), all the graphs doesn't start from the origin(0,0), coz date&time influencing, how could I fix this any suggestions please